# Polymer component for form that returns Json

Tags: polymer

I'm designing up component that I want to return a Json model of the internal form inputs . How do I do this?

And how would I have retrieved this Json into other components?

This component will be combined with other components to make larger models.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with something like [this](http://codepen.io/MWalid/full/wBWNmR/).

You also may handle `select(s)` or [`core-selector(s)`](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-selector) inside your form.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by internal form inputs, but if you just want to save form inputs to a json string see my https://github.com/delebash/KnockoutContactPolymer, this is just the default Knockout contact example converted to Polymer.
Demo app here http://delebash.github.io/KnockoutContactPolymer/

Note: I am using Chrome Canary, so if you are not using Canary you will need to add the polyfills.

In this example you can see how I am saving the form data to json.  Basically whatever your model is for your element you just JSON.stringify(this.contacts);

In my example this.contacts is the model.  As far as passing data, see https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/communication.html, I am still working through this myself so I don't have an example app to demonstrate this, but hopefully this will get you started.